# Calling different implementation of a class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 2 different implementation of a interface `KafkaMetricsReporter` name it `implementation1` and `implementation2`. Each of the implementation has `start` method which starts few threads.

From another class I have to instantiate both `implementation1` and `implementation2`and then run `start` methods of each class. Although I can do it one by one in the given class but is there any cleaner way to do this, so that in future if I have to add one more implementation it would be be easier to do so.
Please give me some pointers.

Correction: `KafkaMetricsReporter` is an interface

Comment: Not clear what you are doing, is `KafkaMetricsReporter` an interface?

Comment: Like, call two methods at once? That doesn't really make sense. But you can use a for loop to go through an array or collection of the imúplementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? Not sure whether I understood the Q.

```
KafkaMetricsReporter[] kmrs = new KafkaMetricsReporter[]{
    new implementation1(),
    new implementation2()
};

for( KafkaMetricsReporter kmr: kmrs ){
    kmr.start();
}
```

Comment: Of course I'm assuming that Kafka... is an interface.

Comment: the poster said KafkaMetricsReporter was a class

Comment: yeah something similar. So when I have a new implementation is it okay to keep on adding it to the array?

Comment: @mxb Same thing, if those others "implement" i.e. extend it, or go from abstract to non-abstract.

Comment: I think the key is to have a common interface

Comment: @mxb Yes. I guess "class" is s.t. sloppily used for "any type", ie. if, enum, "real" class.

Comment: @laune the poster updated the post, it is an interface

Comment: I would rather give the list of implementation class info in a config file so that when ever a new implementation is added we don't have to change code and compile it .

Comment: @srsyogesh Well, if you have to write another implementation class, you'll have to compile. And you'll have to change the config file. And to design, test and implement reading and executing it. Not a free lunch ticket, exactly...

Comment: @laune: Yes , you are right , i again assume the new types if it gets added as part of another library/jar (in java ??) , then we need to compile that for sure but atleast we can avoid compiling the assembly/jar which uses those implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a cleaner  and traditional way. That is [Programming with Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming).

Make an interface with `start()` method and let the other two classes implement it.

**Edit:**
If it an interface, you are almost and a small code needed. Put all the references in an List/Array/Any container.

Just loop on them

```
for( KafkaMetricsReporter  kmr : yourListorArray){
          kmr.start(); 
}
```

That call's all instances start method.

Comment: True, but I doubt this is what the question was asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the client code you can reference the interface directly. For example:

```
public class Impl1 implements KafkaMetricsReporter {
 //...
}
public class Impl2 implements KafkaMetricsReporter {
}

class Client {
  public method() {
    KafkaMetricsReporter reporter1 = new Impl1();
    KafkaMetricsReporter reporter2 = new Impl2();

    reporter1.start();
    reporter2.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: i completely get this point but my question was is this extensible? What if I add few more implementation?

Comment: what do you mean for extensible? with this pattern you can add more implementations if the adhere to the `KafkaMetricsReporter ` interface